# How to display dynamic placeholder text of <v-text-field> in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

The text field is somewhat like this:

```
<v-text-field v-model="input" placeholder="(0 - 200)">
</v-text-field>
```

Vue.js `data` contains:

```
export default {
data () {
    return {
        input: '',
        proposed: 0  
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like the placeholder to display something like this:

`placeholder="Proposed quantity: 2 (0 - 200)"`

Tried setting the `proposed` variable with e.g.:

```
a) placeholder="Proposed quantity: {proposed} (0 - 200)"
b) placeholder="Proposed quantity: `${proposed}` (0 - 200)"
c) placeholder="Proposed quantity: " + proposed + " (0 - 200)"
```

and none worked.

Any other ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to bind the `placeholder` to your data object using `:` or `v-bind:placeholder ...` like :

```
  :placeholder="'Proposed quantity: '+proposed+ ' (0 - 200)'"
```

or

```
  v-bind:placeholder="'Proposed quantity: '+proposed+ ' (0 - 200)'"
```

Comment: I think you are meaning to say `  :placeholder="'Proposed quantity: ' + proposed + ' (0 - 200)'"`. because the syntax you just posted is invalid

Comment: Beat me to that :)